# Matlab-Arduino live plotting

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-communication

I am trying to send data from my arduino to matlab and use the GUI. I want to read continously the data even when no button is pressed. In order to so, i have to use the fscanf function but i don't know where to put it. There is definitely a while loop that waits the events(such as a pushed button) in which this function should be placed. I am just a beginner so this might be a silly question for you.
Thank you in advance!

```
function varargout = UltraPlot(varargin)

global a;
global k;
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
               'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
               'gui_OpeningFcn', @UltraPlot_OpeningFcn, ...
               'gui_OutputFcn',  @UltraPlot_OutputFcn, ...
               'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
               'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
disp('Ultraplot');


function UltraPlot_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

global a;
global k;
a = serial('COM3');
fopen(a);
handles.output = hObject;


guidata(hObject, handles);


disp('Opening');


function varargout = UltraPlot_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;
global a;
global k;
disp('varargout');

function Start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global a;
global k;
fprintf(a,'%d',1);
disp('Button pressed');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set Matlab to wait for any data from Arduino in a while loop, check this sample code :

```
clear;clc;
S=serial('com18'); % Create an S Object
data=0;
set(S,'inputbuffersize',4096,'timeout',20); % Set serial communication     parameter
fopen(S); % Open serial communcation

   while (1)
        if s.bytesavailable>0 % If data from Arduino is available
          data=fscanf(S);
          data = str2num(data);
          % Do whatever you want with data here...
        end
     data=0;
   end
```